# jQuery looping checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that contains many checkboxes. There are a set of checkboxes that have an ID prefixed with pbfam_ and it is only these I am interested in.

When a user clicks on one of these, I need to get a list of the IDs from that subset of only the ones that are checked, and I need it to be a comma delimited string of the IDs.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="pdfam_711131" />
<label for="pdfam_711131" class="VIEWBOX">Temporary Staff</label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="pdfam_711341" />
<label for="pdfam_711341" class="VIEWBOX">Other Contractors</label>
<br />
```

There are about 40 of these checkboxes. What I'm looking for is a string like:

`"pdfam_711131, pdfam_711341"`

I've tried various things and nothing has worked. I'm quite new to jQuery. This gives me a list of checked ones and returns the checked value in an alert and I was trying to mess around with this but I have got nowhere.

```
$('input:checkbox[id^="pdfam_"]:checked').each(function(){alert($(this).attr("id")););
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is to use `.map()` to make an array of the IDs, then use `.toArray().join(", ")` to get your string.

```js
var s = $('input:checkbox[id^="pdfam_"]:checked')
  .map(function(i, el) { return el.id })
  .toArray()
  .join(", ");
  
console.log(s);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" checked id="pdfam_711131" />
<label for="pdfam_711131" class="VIEWBOX">Temporary Staff</label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" checked id="pdfam_711341" />
<label for="pdfam_711341" class="VIEWBOX">Other Contractors</label>
<br />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all those are selected followed by [Join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).The [get() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) returns a specified element from a Map object.

```js
console.log($('input:checkbox[id^="pdfam_"]:checked').map(function() {
   return this.id || null;
}).get().join(','))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" checked id="pdfam_711131" />
<label for="pdfam_711131" class="VIEWBOX">Temporary Staff</label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" checked id="pdfam_711341" />
<label for="pdfam_711341" class="VIEWBOX">Other Contractors</label>
<br />
```